# jQuery data() listen when it gets changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible (if yes how) to check, detect, listen or watch if

```
$('body').data('myValue',false)
```

changes to true?

Of course I change it somewhere to true. The clue is I change it when an animation finishes and need to check somewhere else if it is finished. So when it changed the value I have to do something..

Comment: Not simply (you could poll for the change with a timer). What is the intended use for this?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie gDay Mate, updated the question, is more info needed?

Comment: You could use an event handler for a custom event, and trigger that when you change the value.

Comment: For animation completion jQuery provides `.promise()` which returns a promise that will complete when the animation queue finishes.. really need to see the overall project, not just this snippet, as the approach (using a flag on body data) seems wrong to begin with.

Comment: You can declare global variable say suppose flag=0, and when value changes to true. you change flag value. Using flag you can keep track

Comment: @SandeepPal You now have literally the same problem with a different variable: how do you get code to fire the moment the value of `flag` changes without calling it yourself?

Comment: @Anthony Grist: we can check value change by calling setInterval() function to look for change. It's just a suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Of course I change it somewhere to true. The clue is I change it when an animation finishes and need to check somewhere else if it is finished.

This is where custom events can be handy. In the place where you change it:

```
$('body').data('myValue', true).trigger('datachanged');
```

and where you need to know:

```
$('body').on('datachanged', function() {
    // Use the updated information
});
```

For more about custom events, search for "custom" on [the `on` API doc page](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [the `trigger` API doc page](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to do this:

1. Use setInterval to check for changes in the element's attributes
2. Use this plugin: http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/. I haven't used this, so i can't say if it works well
3. Use the **[DOMAttrModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)** DOM event. IE's equivalent is **propertychange**. This doesn't have great browser support, so it would be a good idea to add a fallback with setInterval.
4. As T.J. Crowder suggested, trigger an event when changing the data attribute

Comment: Re #3: No DOM attributes are modified when you set data via jQuery's `data` function. `data` sets the data in an internal cache of jQuery's, not on the element. It's a common misconception that `data` will set `data-*` attributes. It won't. It *reads* them to initialize the data cache, and that's all. To work interactively with `data-*` attributes, you have to use `attr`, not `data`.